# How to back and select another product in product list [selenium python]

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have problem with going to previous site.

```
        lenPL = len(self.productList)
        counter = 0
```

here I iterate on all product meet conditions

```
    for productCard in self.productList: 
        productCard.click()`

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email-notification']").send_keys("test@test.com")
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Powiadom o dostępności']").click()

        self.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

I previous line I want to back, and select another product

```
CatPage.py


class CatPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver    
    allProducts = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='category-products'] // li[contains(@class,'item')]/div/div")
    testprod = (By.XPATH, "//img[@alt='RustykalneUchwyty.pl']")    
    def getAllGroupedToNotifi(self):
        productToTest = []
        for product in (self.driver.find_elements(*CatPage.allProducts)):
            if product.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='description-wrapper']/div[@class='btn-border btn-border-product-list']"):
                productToTest.append(product)
        print('CatPage.productToTest**', productToTest)
        return productToTest
```

ProdPage.py

```
class ProdPage:

    def __init__(self, driver, productList):
            self.driver = driver
        self.productList = productList
        def signUp(self):
        lenPL = len(self.productList)
        counter = 0
        for productCard in self.productList:
            productCard.click()
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email-notification']").send_keys("test@test.com")
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Powiadom o dostępności']").click()
            self.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            # counter =+1
            # if counter == lenPL:
            #     break
        time.sleep(2)
        return True
```

get info about selenium - how to back and select another element.

Here is my another way to back and open another product, but still doesn't work

```
    def test_e2e(self, setup):
        #przeskrolowanie w celu załadowania lisitngu
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
        #przejście do kategorii
        category = CatPage(self.driver)
        productsToTestList = category.getAllGroupedToNotifi()
        productCard = ProdPage(self.driver,productsToTestList)
        counter = 0
        while counter < 5:
            productsToTestList[counter].click()
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email-notification']").send_keys("test@seart.pl")
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Powiadom o dostępności']").click()
            counter+=1
            self.driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            time.sleep(5)
        # productCard.signUp()
```

Comment: Post the URL to debug.

Comment: Thank you in advance. https://rustykalneuchwyty.pl/133-drzwi-przesuwne-rustykalne-drewniane

Comment: What is the exact flow of your code, I can't find the "//input[@id='email-notification']" in the above page.

Comment: I though you want get root page. I iterate of this page to find first el (e.g. https://rustykalneuchwyty.pl/drzwi-przesuwne-debowe-one-board-ze-sznurem.html ) and '//input[@id='email-notification''  is here. Sorry

Comment: All hope in your. No one else can advise me

Comment: @AbiSaran Can you look at this again? I added another way to do my operation in edit. But still I don't get what I need